# CSS Drop Down menus won't align with parent Menus

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, alignment

Having trouble getting the drop-down menus to be directly aligned with the parent ones - at the moment they always fall from the center of the top one, see image.

[image]

My code:

```css
body {
  background: url('body-bkg.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
}

#navMenu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}


/*controls top parent box in navigation bar*/

#navMenu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}


/*controls top parent box in navigation bar*/

#navMenu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: hsla(0, 9%, 202%, 0.7);
  float: left;
}

#navMenu ul li {
  position: relative;
}


/*controls link text parent and children boxes in navigation bar*/

#navMenu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  color: #2e1c1c;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}


/*controls children boxes in navigation bar*/

#navMenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 31px;
}


/*controls children boxes in navigation bar when hovered on parent box*/

#navMenu ul li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
}


/*controls parent box when hovered on children box*/

#navMenu li:hover {
  background: #387cf7;
}


/*controls child box when hovered on child box*/

#navMenu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="navMenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Destinations</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Asia</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Africa</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Europe</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">North America</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">South America</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Antartica</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Holiday Types</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Short Breaks</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Beaches</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Adventure</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Walking</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Continents</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Safari</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Cruise</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Family</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Ultimate</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">When to go</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Winter</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Spring</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Summer</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Autumn</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Corporate</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Special Offers</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You might have to show us your HTML also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution may work for you:

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/hYf8N/)**

I see you're using `visibility:hidden` a lot, but In situations like this I find `display: none` to be easier to work with.

CSS:

```
#navMenu ul ul {
    // current styles

    left: 0px;
}
```